# Want to Print the text on the XPath

Tags: javascript, node.js, appium, webdriver-io, appium-android

```
const myAdress = (`My Address = +${'//android.widget.TextView[@index="1"]'}`);
console.log(myAdress);
```

Want to print the text on this specific XPath but it prints this as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const myAdress = (`My Address is ${$('//android.widget.TextView[@index="1"]').getText()}`);
console.log(myAdress);
```

You have problems with brackets.

This is clearer:

```
const element = $('//android.widget.TextView[@index="1"]') 
const text = element.getText()
console.log(`My address is ${text}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial text in xpath instead of appending text such as

```
String address = "//*[contains(@text,'replace your address')]"


String printAddress= driver.findElementByXPath(address).getText();
log.info(printAddress);
```